# Import bulk geotagged images stored in web drive using table and convert this link into points

Tags: qgis, point, geotag, link

[image]

In the Excel sheet added. one column includes rows of links to geotagged images stored in webdrive. Is it possible to import from these links and convert it into point polygons?

When the points are converted the attribute table needed to contain the unique id given in the Excel table against each point.

Comment: You'd need to access the EXIF data of the images, where the georeference is stored.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to extract the `EXIF` data of your images and then create new features based on the `GPSTAGS` property reading the `Longitude` and `Latitude` values.

This script reads a table layer (already loaded to `QGIS`) called `location_data_for_cross_check` - maybe you need to change it and reads the `id`, `name` and `link` attribute (in this order).

Then it loops all the entries from the table layer and creates a feature for every entry based on the geotagged images.

If you want to show the images with `QGIS` using `HTML` fields, this [article](https://opengislab.com/blog/2020/8/23/mapping-and-viewing-geotagged-photos-in-qgis) is very useful.

```py
from PIL import Image
from PIL.ExifTags import TAGS, GPSTAGS
import requests
import json

# Get Exif Function:
def get_exif(file):
    exif = file._getexif()
    result = {}
    if exif is not None:
        for key, value in list(exif.items()):
            name = TAGS.get(key, key)
            exif[name] = exif.pop(key)

        if 'GPSInfo' in exif:
            for key in exif['GPSInfo'].keys():
                decode = ExifTags.GPSTAGS.get(key,key)
                result[decode] = exif['GPSInfo'][key]

    return result

# Helper Function to convert GPS Tags data to degrees
def convert_to_degress(val):
    return float(val[0]) + float(val[1])/60 + float(val[2]) / (3600*100) 

# Get Layer from project
dataLayer = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName("location_data_for_cross_check")[0]

# Create Temporary geojson dict
featureCollection = {
    'type': 'FeatureCollection',
    'features': []
}

# Iterate features / rows
for feature in dataLayer.getFeatures():
    # Get Attributes
    featureAttributes = feature.attributes()
    id = featureAttributes[0]
    name = featureAttributes[1]
    link = featureAttributes[2]
    
    # Get exif data
    exifData = {}
    img = Image.open(requests.get(link, stream=True).raw)
    exifData = get_exif(img)
    
    # If exifData is empty we will skip
    if bool(exifData):
        latitude = convert_to_degress(exifData['GPSLatitude'])
        longitude = convert_to_degress(exifData['GPSLongitude'])
            
        # Create Feature
        geojsonFeature = {
          'type': 'Feature',
          'id': id,
          'properties': {
            'id': id,
            'name': name,
            'link': link
          },
          'geometry': {
            "type": 'Point',
            "coordinates": [
              longitude,
              latitude
            ]
          }
        }
        
        # Append to FeatureCollection
        featureCollection["features"].append(geojsonFeature)
    else:
        print("No Geotags available for id: " + str(id))

# Add ImageLayer 
imageLayer = QgsVectorLayer(json.dumps(featureCollection), "imageLayer", "ogr")
QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(imageLayer)
```

Comment: thankyou, this works. this method need good system and network if working with high volume of images.

Comment: Sure - can't see any other solution if you are doing it locally. Otherwise you would need some pre-processing in the cloud / on some server. Or your image hosting / webdrive has some API capabilities to query exif information.